# Why is S.D. of the sample mean getting smaller as I increase the sample size?

Tags: standard-error

My guess is that if a take a sample with $n$ observations ($n$ = sample size), average them and plot it and repeating the same thing for a lot of times then I am getting "dupplicates along the way", meaning that observations which occured in the sample nr 1 could also occur in the sample nr $x$. So I don't always get new data, therefore my SD gets smaller.

It's a little bit strange/counter intuitive for me that repeating the same process of taking the average of a sample and plot it , again and again will get the sample mean closer and closer to the true pop. mean. But S.D. of the sample mean keeps varrying with the sample size as opposed to the mean of the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard deviation of the sample mean is given by $$\sigma_{\bar x}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},$$ where $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation. Notice that it is not a function of the mean (let's call the mean $\mu.$) Since $\sigma$ is constant, $\sigma_{\bar x}$ is really just a function of the sample size, and as you can see from the formula, a larger sample size means a smaller standard deviation of the sample mean. This is intuitive - don't you expect that collecting more data will in general produce a less variable result for your sample mean?

Comment: I can understand the confusion though since the most common definition for the sample standard deviation $$s=\sqrt{\frac{\sum \left( x_i-\bar{x} \right )^2}{n-1}}$$ includes the sample mean.  Like your example, a computationally equivalent sample standard deviation (though less common form),  $$s=\sqrt{\frac{\sum x^2 - \frac{\left( \sum x \right )^2}{n}}{n-1}}$$ does not include the mean.